# How to convert series to dataframe?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, series, typeconverter

There are elements of series type. I want to convert these elements into dataframes. However, I cannot do it because of the dictionaries and lists in it. How can I return null for non-null fields and write the non-blank answers to the dataframe?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGQVe.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **"to_frame"** function to convert the series into a dataframe:

```
s = pd.Series(["a", "b", "c"],
              name="letters")

df = s.to_frame()
```

Comment: can u check the image that I add please

Answer (score 0):

If you want a result like in the image for the two series you provided, you can do something like this:

```
s1 = {'q1':'apple','q2':'12','q4':'banana','q5':'How are you?'}
s2 = {'q1': 'kiwi','q3':'very good','q5':'Wht?'}
df = pd.DataFrame([s1,s2])
```